# air conditioner no longer working in 2005 Chevy Impala?

Tags: ac

so after getting my breaks fixed (which was warped) the air conditioner stopped working. In winter it can only provide cold air, and in summer it can only provide hot air.

how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure if it was working before the brake job was done, but is there any relevance to this? Was it working when it went in, and now it is not?

Comment: it's difficult to say because I remember turning it on this summer and it was blasting hot air. I haven't used it for a while before it went in for a fix

Comment: The brakes will not cause the AirCon to malfunction. A fault on the accelerator pedal switch will though. The accelerator pedal switch  will turn the AirCon off on full throttle.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're not running the heater in the summer, seems like your compressor is not kicking on. I would begin by checking the charge in your system, as a low charge would keep your compressor from coming on. You can move on from there, but there is not point in continuing, if there is a leak in your system.

Comment: how can I check the charge? is this something that I can trouble shoot or need to take to a shop?

Comment: I would take it to a shop, unless you own the gauges. Basically, plug gauges in and run AC. Should see vacuum on low and some pressure quantity (depends on car) on high.

Answer (score 2):

Your AirCon system has a high pressure side and a low pressure side. The heater assembly will have a shut off valve which operates to prevent hot coolant from the engine reaching the heater radiator. Some vehicles will have an internal flap to divert the air from the blower fan passing through the heater radiator and then heating the air from the AirCon evaporater. A quick check is to watch, **keep hands clear - watch**, the AirCon compressor. With an assistant in the vehicle and with the engine running, ask the assistant to turn the AirCon on and after a few seconds off again . Repeat this a few times. If the system is working, the clutch assembly on the drive end of the compressor will move in and out and make an operational clicking sound. If the compressor operates, run the engine for about five minutes with the AirCon turned on. Then with the **engine now turned off**, touch each pipe on the compressor briefly. One pipe, the high pressure metal pipe will now be hot. The other pipe, low pressure pipe will now be cold. This will tell you if you have a gas charge in the system. If the temperatures are present, run the engine again and check how the AirCon is working inside the vehicle. If the heater is blowing out hot air then the control switch, cut off valve or diverter flap are not working and are allowing the heater to heat your AirCon evaporator cold output air. An AirCon system needs to be run occasionally to keep the gas seals oiled and sealing the system. Not running the AirCon system can allow the gas seals to harden and allow the gas to escape. The system may also suffer damage and malfunction. All AirCon repair work will require an AirCon service machine. A service need will mean a visit to your favourite repair shop.

Comment: This is a very good answer that could be further improved by some thoughtful formatting. At a minimum some line breaks would help readability. Your procedure could be turned into a numbered list to highlight the step-by-step nature.